# How to configure the foward/rewind step size (in seconds)?

Tags: vlc

The default setting of `vlc` is to skip x seconds when forwarding/rewinding based on the video length (there's also the possibility to make small steps (hotkey for that is configurable)). How can I set the steps to be a seconds long with a depending on the video length? Can I overwrite the default forward/rewind hotkeys (mouse wheel up/down when hovering over progress bar without pressing further keys) to consider this setting?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for a solution, but [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_8490449_change-skip-time-vlc.html) article describes how to do what you seen to want. I came across both your question and the article when I was looking for a solution myself. It worked for me on Win7 and will hopefully work on Ubuntu as well.

#### Steps:

1. Launch VLC. Click "Tools" in the top menu bar, then click "Preferences" to open VLC's preferences section.
2. Click the radio button next to "All" in the lower left-hand corner to display VLC's "Advanced settings" section. Click the arrow next to "Interfaces" in the left-hand column, and then click "Hotkeys settings."
3. Click the text box next to the jump size you want to change in the "Jump sizes" section. Type the length of time, in seconds, that you want to set as the skip length. Repeat the process for all of the skip lengths that you want to change.
4. Click "Save" to apply the new skip times, and close the "Preferences" window.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Though I'd love to know if there's a way to get non-integer step times without using the Jump to time plugin.

Comment: on my VLC `2.1.6 Rincewind` the steps are: Options (in window menu) -> Preferences (also Ctrl+P) -> Interface (the left menu) -> Seeking -- there set Short jump and `apply`.

Comment: https://www.vlchelp.com/navigate-video-audio-efficiently/

Comment: You can also run `grep '\(key-jump\|jump-size\)' ~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` in the shell to see all the relevant options in your config file.

Answer (score 9):

To complete on Roney answer, note that VLC has both a normal step mode (10s by default, by pressing `right/left arrows`) and a short step mode (3s by default, by pressing `Shift+right/left arrows`). To configure the time, cf Roney Michael's answer.