# Which Audio Player has Buttons for --15 sec and ++15 sec or so, not just Jump to Start or End of Recording?

Tags: rhythmbox, audio-player

Sometimes there are buttons on websites that let you fast-forward or rewind by 10 or 15 seconds or so.

I miss such buttons in Parole, Rhythmbox or their siblings.

Especially in very long recordings, it is almost impossible to skip forward or backward by only a few seconds because the sensitivity of the slider is not adequate: moving the slider sometimes means moving the playback position too much. This is where such additional buttons would be very useful.

- Which of the available audio players already has those navigation
  buttons?
- Which one can be equipped with them by a plug-in?

Comment: vlc can play audio files, and it has many settings and plugins, so I would assume it could handle this but I don't know for sure/how so I'm leaving this as a comment

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470697/how-to-configure-the-foward-rewind-step-size-in-seconds

Comment: Unfortunately loading an mp3 file into vlc seems to take as long as the recording to be loaded. That's not an attractive choice.